# Substitute multiple parts of a URL with encoded string

Tags: regex, perl

I've found this Perl code:

```
$url = "http://example.com/?param1=#param1#&param2=#param2#"
$param1="hello";
$param2="world";
$url =~ s/#param1#/$param1/g;
$url =~ s/#param2#/$param2/g;
```

where the `=~` operator applies a regex and replaces the original variable (`$url`).
Is there a way in Perl to apply the change to another variable, and apply the two regexes in one statement?

Something that looks like this:

```
$url_template = "http://example.com/?param1=#param1#&param2=#param2#"
$param1="hello";
$param2="world";
$url = $url_template ~ s/#param1#/$param1/g ~ s/#param2#/$param2/g;
```

This code does not work. The question is: how to make it work?

Also, is there a better way to format strings? For example

```
String.format("http://example.com/?param1={param1}&param2={param2}", {"param1": param1, "param2": param2}).
```

Finally, is there a better way to format URL parameters (so that they are encoded properly)? For example

```
URL.format("http://example.com/?param1={param1}&param2={param2}", {"param1": param1, "param2": param2}).
```

---

**Update:**
Full answer based on choroba and aleroot:

```
my $template_url = "http://example.com/?param1=#param1#&param2=#param2#";
my %params = (param1 => 'hello1', param2 => 'world2');
(my $url = $template_url) =~ s/#(.*?)#/$params{$1}/g;
```

For encoding of URLs, use [URL::Encode](http://p3rl.org/URL%3a%3aEncode).

Comment: Instead of manipulating URLs with regular expressions, it's much safer to use the URI::URL module.

Comment: @andy, URL::Encode is already mentioned as part of the updated solution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Perl binding operator is `=~`, not `~=`. It is not possible to make two substitutions at once, however it is possible to make the substitution happen as many times as needed with `/g`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $url = 'http://example.com/?param1=#param1#&param2=#param2#';
my %params = ( param1 => 'hello',
               param2 => 'world',
             );
$url =~ s/#(.*?)#/$params{$1}/g;
print $url, "\n";
```

For encoding of URLs, use [URL::Encode](http://p3rl.org/URL::Encode).

Answer (score 1):

To store the regex substitution to another variable (`$newurl`) :

```
($newurl = $url) =~ s/#param1#/$param1/g;
```